# Search between two dates w/ datarows in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, date, data-binding

I am trying to search between two dates in a `bound source` (SQL table) in VB 2010, using data rows.  Since 'between' in unsupported with the data rows function, I used `<` and `>`.
So I run this code and the output is 900+ entries when the actual number of entries is 8. After hitting my button a second time without changing anything, the correct number of entries appears.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _ 
                                                    Handles cmdSearch.Click

    Dim Expression As String
    Dim OrderStr As String = "Area"
    Dim DateStr As String
    Dim StartDate As String
    Dim EndDate As String
    Dim Shift As String = ""
    Dim Area As String = ""
    Dim Product As String

    If (DtpStartDate.Value = Nothing Or DtpEndDate.Value = Nothing) Then
        MsgBox("Please input a start and end date.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If (radShiftAllSearch.Checked <> True _ 
            And radShiftOneSearch.Checked <> True 
            And radShiftTwoSearch.Checked <> True _ 
            And radShiftThreeSearch.Checked <> True) Then
        MsgBox("Please select a shift to search for.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case True
        Case radShiftOneSearch.Checked
            Shift = " AND [Shift] = '1'"
        Case radShiftTwoSearch.Checked
            Shift = " AND [Shift] = '2'"
        Case radShiftThreeSearch.Checked
            Shift = " AND [Shift] = '3'"
        Case radShiftAllSearch.Checked
            Shift = " AND ([Shift] = '1' OR [Shift] = '2' OR [Shift] = '3')"
    End Select


    **StartDate = DtpStartDate.Value.Subtract(oneday)
    EndDate = DtpEndDate.Value.Add(oneday)
    'StartDate = Format(DtpStartDate.Value.Subtract(oneday), "M/dd/yyyy")
    'EndDate = Format(DtpEndDate.Value.Add(oneday), "M/dd/yyyy")
    DateStr = "[Dates] > '" & StartDate & "' AND [Dates] < '" & EndDate & "'"**

    If (txtProductSearch.Text = "") Then
        Product = ""
    Else
        Product = "AND [Product] LIKE '" & txtProductSearch.Text & "'"
    End If

    For h As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
        Dim XDRV As DataRowView = CType(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(h), DataRowView)
        Dim XDR As DataRow = XDRV.Row
        Dim XDisplayMember As String = XDR(CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember).ToString()
        If (Area = "") Then
            Area = Area & " AND ([Area] LIKE '" & XDisplayMember & "'"
        Else
            Area = Area & " OR [Area] LIKE '" & XDisplayMember & "'"
        End If
    Next

    If (Area <> "") Then
        Area = Area & ")"
    End If

    Expression = DateStr & Product & Shift & Area
    TextBox4.Text = Expression

    Dim SearchRows() As DataRow = _ 
    ProductionDataSet.Tables("Production_Daily").Select(Expression, OrderStr)
    'foundcount = SearchRows.Count - 1

    DataGridView1.DataSource = SearchRows
    DataGridView1.Show()


End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: i was not able to find anything suspicious. but one thing i would try is to remove the `add(oneday)`and `subtract(oneday)` function calls and try to use `<=` `>=` instad of `>` `<`.....

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however this is what i ended up using

Expression = "Select * FROM Production_Daily WHERE " & DateStr & Product & Shift & Area

        Production_DailyTableAdapter1.selectcommand.CommandText = Expression